# XML Serialization with Different Subclasses

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a super class and two subclasses and I want to serialize the objects of the subclasses as a list and deserialize it

I tried to use a super class list which had objects from both subclasses but ended up in an exception.

Is there any way to do it?

```
Type1 t = new Type1() { text="123" ,opt1=true,opt2=true};
Type2 t1 = new Type2() { text="1234",isAnswer=false};
Question q1 = new Question() { text="12321"};
Question q2 = new Question() { text = "12321" };
List<Question> q = new List<Question>() { t1 };
FileStream fs = new FileStream("aa.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Question>));
//Exception is generated here InvalidOperationException
//there was error genearating the XML document
xs.Serialize(fs, q);

fs.Close();
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  What have you tried? What exception did you get? Your question doesn't give us enough detail to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: InvalidoperationException
There was an error generating the XML document.

Type1 t = new Type1() { text="123" ,opt1=true,opt2=true};
            Type2 t1 = new Type2() { text="1234",isAnswer=false};
            Question q1 = new Question() { text="12321"};
            Question q2 = new Question() { text = "12321" };
            List<Question> q = new List<Question>() { q1,q2,t1 };
            FileStream fs = new FileStream("aa.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Question>));

Comment: @M.Babcock - good point - thanks - re-added.

Comment: Ok, sorry i'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: I think we need to see the classes.. the code is a mess and one can't infer from it how the class are related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing the types to be known to the serializer, such as,

`serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), extraTypes);` where extraTypes is an array of types that you have to be serialized.